# Generate items into galley

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have this React Material-UI component implemented in Typescript:

```
<Grid container direction="row" justifyContent="flex-start" alignItems="flex-start">
                <Grid item xs={5}>
                    <Box m={5} pl={10}>
                        ...... some body text..........
                    </Box>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

How I can generate several `Grid item` from a array and add a horizontal scroll bar to list them if the list is too big?

Comment: Is the code shown the body of a "`Grid item`" or is "`Grid item`" something inside that code?

Comment: "Grid item" is something inside that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `map` method to render a component for each element of your array. As for the horizontal scrolling, there are several ways to do this, but one way I've found that works well is to place the items in a flex-box container and put that container inside another container that scrolls horizontally. Also with this approach you'll need to set `width: fit-content` on the row component so that it expands outside of the parent component.

Let's say your data is stored in an array called `items` and the component for each is `GridItem`. Then we can do this:

```js
function App() {
  const items = [{name: "One"}, {name: "Two"}, {name: "Three"}, {name: "Four"}, {name: "Five"}, {name: "Six"}];
  
  return (
    <div className="scroll-wrapper">
      <div className="row">
        {items.map(e => <GridItem name={e.name}/>)}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function GridItem({ name }) {
  return (
    <div className="grid-item">
      {name}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```css
.scroll-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 1rem; /* for the scroll bar */
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: fit-content;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 30vw;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"/>
```